# How to add "+" and "%" to numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Animation of numbers is implemented in the block on the site. When scrolling to the section, the counter starts and the numbers begin to be counted towards the given number. Only 4 digits I need to add the "+" sign to the first three, and add the "%" sign to the last one. How can i do this?
I need to be: 11+, 300+, 140+, 40%.

```js
(function() {
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    var statistics = $(".statistics");
    var numbers = $(".__js_number");
    var animationIsDone = false;
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if ($("*").is(".statistics")) {
      var offset = statistics.offset().top;

      if (!animationIsDone && scroll >= offset) {
        animateNumbers();
      }

      $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if (!animationIsDone && scroll >= offset) {
          animateNumbers();
        }
      });
    }

    function animateNumbers() {
      numbers.each(function() {
        var endValue = parseInt($(this).attr("data-end-value"), 10);

        $(this).easy_number_animate({
          start_value: 0,
          end_value: endValue,
          duration: 1800,
        });
      });

      animationIsDone = true;
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statistics__item-value">
  <span class="__js_number venus" data-end-value="11">0</span>
</div>
<div class="statistics__item-value">
  <span class="__js_number venus" data-end-value="300">0</span>
</div>
<div class="statistics__item-value">
  <span class="__js_number venus" data-end-value="140">0</span>
</div>
<div class="statistics__item-value">
  <span class="__js_number venus" data-end-value="40">0</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The animate functions work best on real numbers. Could you just add the characters you want as a suffix in the HTML markup?

```
<div class="statistics__item-value">
  <span class="__js_number venus" data-end-value="11">0</span>+
</div>
<div class="statistics__item-value">
  <span class="__js_number venus" data-end-value="300">0</span>+
</div>
<div class="statistics__item-value">
  <span class="__js_number venus" data-end-value="140">0</span>+
</div>
<div class="statistics__item-value">
  <span class="__js_number venus" data-end-value="40">0</span>%
</div>
```

Comment: I upvoted this but I wonder if this might not be a use case for HTML entities, to make the symbols stand out instead of just "+" which our eyes might tend to scan over; reference at https://unicode-table.com/en/html-entities/

Comment: *he animate functions work best on real numbers* <-- Actually, they ONLY work with numbers .